# Where to put the download specific code?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, cakephp

After a few native iOS/Android projects I'm now on a CakePHP project. On this project I've learned to keep the main part of the model specific code inside the model itself. This worked great, because of the cleaner controllers.

Today I'll start on a native iOS/Android project which retrieves it's main part of the data from a web service. Now I've questioned wether to put the download specific code inside the model or just create some kind of download helper. In CakePHP all the retrieval of the data was done inside the model. It made the code quite silk and smooth :) What's your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my apps (both android and ios - same functionality, two platforms), I created a "download helper" class, whose job is to marshal requests from app to the server and then parse the responses into a format that the app's model can understand.  Technically it's still part of the mode, if you're after a clean separation, but it provides a nice layer between the actual "model" and the raw data, so that I can modify just one class if the source or the format of the data changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, as you mention the model will be the only one connected to the download helper class? It's not the controller connecting both?

Comment: @BenGroot That's not exactly what I meant.  The controller will be connected to the model.  The model is responsible for producing/formatting the data - and it uses the helper class to do that.  Depending on the implementation of the helper, it may need to use some of the controller logic, but it does not have to.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should use some download helper.. like Async Task for downloading from web service.. because the main thread shouldn't be waiting long for downloading..and in new version.. android 4.0.3.. i saw that when you try to download some thing on main thread.. which takes time.. your application will crash...though, in older versions i didn't crash... but using download helper is recommended..